# Getting MS SQL Server Exception User Message in Delphi exception

Tags: sql-server, delphi, exception

I´m using Datasnap.DBClient to access the SQL Server Database from my Delphi application.

I have a logger that logs every exception in my app, but I´m finding SQL exceptions messages really unfriendlies.

Example: When I catch the SQL exception in Delphi the message I get is:

> EOleException: SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207

If I open a trace in SQL Profiler I get two messages:

The first one, **Exception** is the same message that the apps shows:

> Exception: Error: 207, Severity: 16, State: 1

The second one, is:

> User Error Message: Invalid column name 'Column1'

Is there any possibility to get this **UserErrorMessage** from the catched Exception in my Delphi app?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you are using Ado or DBExpress, but if it's DBExpress, you probably wouldn't be asking the question (see Update below).

The `TAdoConnection` has an `Errors` object (see definition in AdoInt.Pas).  To
investigate it, I used a stored proc on the server defined as

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRaiseError](@AnError int)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @Msg Char(20)
  if @AnError > 0
    begin
      Select @Msg = 'MyError ' + convert(Char(8), @AnError)
      RaisError(@Msg, 16, -1)
    end
  else
    select 1
END
```

Then, in my Delphi code I have something like this:

```
uses [...] AdoInt, AdoDB, [...]

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : String;
  IErrors : Errors;
  IError : Error;
  ErrorCount : Integer;
  i : Integer;
begin
  S := 'exec spRaiseError ' + Edit1.Text;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := S;
  try
    AdoQuery1.Open;
  except
    IErrors := AdoConnection1.Errors;
    ErrorCount := IErrors.Count;
    for i := 0 to ErrorCount - 1 do begin
      IError := IErrors.Item[i];
      S := Format('error: %d, source: %s description: %s', [i, IError.Source, IError.Description]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    end;
    Caption := IntToStr(ErrorCount);
  end;
end;
```

If you try it out, you should find that the contents of the `Errors` collection
is cumulative, so it *should* capture the second message you are after. However, I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say you are using "Datasnap dbclient":  "DBClient" is the unit  which declares the TClientDataSet, but you may be using that with ADO or DBExpress.  I'm not sure that the DBX Sql Server driver has any counterpart to the AdoConnections Errors collection that you can get at through using the DBX components.

**Update**  Using the above code, if I do a SELECT which deliberately refers to a non-existent column, 'aname', I get this in Memo1:

> error: 0, source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server description: Invalid column name 'aname'.

, but it does not report the error 207 you get.

If I do the same SELECT in a DBX project and trap the exception as I open the ClientDataSet connected to the SqlQuery, as in the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : String;
begin
  S := 'select id, aname from atable';
  ClientDataSet1.CommandText := S;
  try
    ClientDataSet1.Open;
  except
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Exception(ExceptObject).Message);
  end;
end;
```

I get this

> SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 8180
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207
>   Invalid column name 'aname'.

which in some ways is a bit more informative. At the same time, your logging function logs this:

```
Fecha: 2017-02-03 18:44:02
Sesion: {2E7176CB-56FD-41C4-BE67-7B9E1D3486B4}
Proyecto: dbxerrors.exe
Aplicación:    
Ruta: D:\aaad7\Ado\
Usuario: ???
Error: SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 8180
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207
Invalid column name 'aname'.

Exception EDatabaseError: SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 8180
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207
Invalid column name 'aname'.

    Exception 
    UnitName : 
    Procedure : 
    Line : 0
    BinaryFileName : 


Fecha: 2017-02-03 18:44:02
Sesion: {2E7176CB-56FD-41C4-BE67-7B9E1D3486B4}
Proyecto: dbxerrors.exe
Aplicación:    
Ruta: D:\aaad7\Ado\
Usuario: ???
Error: SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 8180
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207
Invalid column name 'aname'
Exception EOleException: SQL State: 42000, SQL Error Code: 8180
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207
Invalid column name 'aname'
    Exception 
    UnitName : 
    Procedure : 
    Line : 0
    BinaryFileName :
```

In case it helps, this is a partial extract of my test project's DFM

```
  object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    ConnectionName = 'MSSQLConnection'
    DriverName = 'MSSQL'
    GetDriverFunc = 'getSQLDriverMSSQL'
    LibraryName = 'dbexpmss.dll'
    LoginPrompt = False
    Params.Strings = (
      'DriverName=MSSQL'
      'HostName=MAT410\ss2014'
      'DataBase=MATest'
      'User_Name=sa'
      'Password=sa'
      'BlobSize=-1'
      'ErrorResourceFile='
      'LocaleCode=0000'
      'MSSQL TransIsolation=ReadCommited'
      'OS Authentication=False')
    VendorLib = 'oledb'
    Left = 40
    Top = 32
  end
  object SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery
    MaxBlobSize = -1
    Params = <>
    SQLConnection = SQLConnection1
    Left = 88
    Top = 32
  end
  object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
    DataSet = SQLQuery1
    Options = [poAllowCommandText]
    Left = 136
    Top = 32
  end
  object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
    Left = 184
    Top = 32
  end
```

As you can see, it is pretty minimalist.  Delphi version is D7 on Win10 64-bit and server is Sql Server 2014.

Comment: Thanks @MartynA. I´m using DBExpress. How did you get that description at the end your answer?

Comment: I´m actually getting the exception with JCLDebugger, I´m not doing a try except to catch it. The idea is to log every SQL Error in a text file.

Comment: @Andres: "How did you get that description at the end your answer"  See the code I've just added to my answer.

Comment: Well @MartynA, thats what I´m doing, but I just get the following error: SQL State: 42S22, SQL Error Code: 207. I´m missing the  "Invalid column name" part. Do I need to set some config in Delphi or SQL Server in order to receive that message?

Comment: @Andres:  Sorry, the code is all there is in my DBX test project, but I've added a text extract of the DFM in case it helps you spot what's different about yours.

Comment: Thanks @MartynA for your time. I cant find any different. Can you please add the following .pas file (http://www.filedropper.com/jclloghandler) in your project and execute it? This unit catches the exception and logs it in a txt file in C:\Log. Then I can tell if the message you get is the same as the one I receive.

Comment: @Andres:  It turned out the PC I was using had an old and incomplete version of Jedi.  I installed a new one and compiled your error-logging unit.  I've added the contents of the log to my answer - as you'll see, it logs essentially the same error as my `Memo,Lines` log.

Comment: Thanks @MartynA. It seems it must be some kind of configuration. I will check it and tell you.